# Contador vectores C++

Tags: c++, array

Tengo que hacer un programa que almacene en un array las notas de 30 alumnos, y que finalice pasados 30 o cuando el alumno introduzca una nota negativa o mas alta de 10, y luego mostrar cuantas veces se ha repetido la nota[i], lo tengo tal que asi, gracias!

```
#include <iostream>

int notas[30];
int n;
int contador = 0;
int i = 0, repeticiones = 0;

do
{
    cout << "Introduce un numero: ";
    cin >> n;

    if ((n >= 0 && n <= 10) && contador <= 30)
    {
        notas[i] = n;
        contador++;
        i++;
        for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++)
        {
            if (notas[i] == n)
            {
                repeticiones++;
            }

            cout << "La nota " << n << " se ha repetido " << repeticiones << " veces \n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "El programa ha finalizado." << endl;
    }

} while ((n >= 0 && n <= 10) && contador <= 30);
```

Comment: La condición de tu `while` y la condición de tu `if` son exactamente iguales. Ya eso es un error de diseño. Si deseas parar el bucle `while` pon una sentencia `break` dentro de tu `else`. Y el bucle hazlo indefinido, como `while(true)`.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que te has encontrado?

Answer (score 1):

Aquí una solución, que a mi criterio es un poco mas simple:

Primero usas un `while` para capturar las notas que ingresa el usuario, y al mismo tiempo, las vas contando (con ayuda de otro arreglo). Después usas otro bucle, un `for`, para mostrar las repeticiones.

Una manera fácil de contar las repeticiones es asignar cada indice de un arreglo a cada nota, y así, cuando aumentamos en uno el valor de `repeticiones[3]` en realidad estamos registrando que la nota `3` apareció una vez más. Espero que los comentarios en el código te ayuden a entenderlo mejor.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // constante para controlar cuantas notas se van a leer
    const int NUM_NOTAS = 30; 

    // arreglo para guardar las notas
    int notas[ NUM_NOTAS ] = {0}; 

    // arreglo para contar las repeticiones,
    // 11  posiciones porque son las posibles calificaciones entre 0 y 10
    int repeticiones[11] = {0};

    int n = 0;
    int contador = 0;

    // se reptite mientras se cumplan dichas condiciones
    while(contador < NUM_NOTAS && n >= 0 && n <= 10 )
    {
        // pedimos y guardamos el número
        cout << "Introduce un numero: ";
        cin >> n;

        notas[contador] = n; // guardamos el número dentro del arreglo.
        ++repeticiones[ n ]; // aumentamos en uno el indice que correponde a la calif.
        ++contador;          // aumentamos en uno el cotador.
    }

    // mensaje que nos indica que terminó el bucle
    cout << "El programa ha finalizado." << endl;

    // recorremos el arreglo donde se contabilizaron las repetciones
    for ( int i = 0; i < 11; ++i)
    {
        // solo imprimimos aquellas que tengan al menos una repetición
        if( repeticiones[i] > 0 )
        {
            cout << "La nota " << i << " se ha repetido " << repeticiones[i] << " veces \n";
        }
    }

}
```

Espero te sirva, ¡saludos!.